# Java String vs String Buffer

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have the following lines from the Java code

```
{        
         String str1=new String("Vivek");
         String str2=new String("Vivek");
         StringBuffer str3=new StringBuffer("Vivek");
         StringBuffer str4=new StringBuffer("Vivek");
         System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
         System.out.println(str3.equals(str4));
}
```

Now i get the output as following

```
    True
    False
```

I cant get why it prints true for String oject and false for objects of StringBuffer?
 Has it to do something with mutability of objects?

Comment: You're a magician! This cannot compile. Did you meant `StringBuffer str3=new StringBuffer("Vivek");`?

Comment: @ZouZou after a small edit: http://ideone.com/xUJgnG

Comment: The `StringBuffer` class does simply not override equals. Since you create two brand new instances, it returns false.

Comment: `StringBuffer` does not override the `equals` method from `Object`.

Comment: `str3.equals(str4)` is equivalent to `object.equals(object)`

Comment: Unrelated note: if you don't need the thread-safty of StringBuffer, use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuffer` does not override `equals` so calls the method of the superclass `Object`. 
If you want to compare content use the `toString` method

```
System.out.println(str3.toString().equals(str4.toString()));
```

Note Since Java 1.5 `StringBuffer` has been superceded by `StringBuilder` as a non-threaded alternative

Comment: In other words, they weren't designed to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `equals` in class `String` has been over-written to compare the content while the `equals` in class `StringBuffer` remained inherited from class Object which compares the address.

See there javadoc for both and you will understand more.

In `String.equals`:

```
Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Overrides: equals(...) in Object
Parameters:
anObject The object to compare this String against
Returns:
true if the given object represents a String equivalent to this string, false otherwise
See Also:
compareTo(String)
equalsIgnoreCase(String)
```

You may use:

```
str3.toString().equals(str4);
```

Comment: Yup...got it now...so the point is that String class overrides the equlas methods from the  Object class and StringBuffer does not...